# C++ Clears file when a new print action takes place

Tags: c++, macos, text, netbeans, file-io

I have a C++ (Made in Netbeans 8 in Mac OS X 10.9) that in short writes to a file then ends the program. Here is the **Meat** of my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

ofstream outfile("NETBEANS_PMCL.txt");

    if(outfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Cant open that file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    outfile << "name" << endl;
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
```

But each time I run the program it rewrites on top of the `name` that was printed the last time I ran the program. **How do I make it so that if there is content on the first line then skip two lines and print and if there is content there skip two lines and print and so on.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ofstream is to write to a file, and what you want is to read to see if there is content, skeep 2 lines, and write new content.

```
std::fstream file("NETBEANS_PMCL.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

After that you may try to read 2 line and write content. Consider the function member getline to read the content.

```
getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

Comment: Using the `fstream::in` `out` and `app` worked if you do, do you know a reference to a site where I can further understand what those statements do?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/
Here you have info about fstream, and looking for the "open" function, you get info about in|out|app. Basically: "in" allow reading, "out" allow writing and "app" append the new content (without removing previous content).